# Find lines that contains a specific string and randomly pick one in c#

Tags: c#, string, text, random, io

So, I have a text file that looks like this:

```
[hello]Hi
[hello]welcome back 
[hello]Hello sir 
[goodbye]goodbye sir
[goodbye]until next time
...
```

And here is a part of the code:

```
string[] responseLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"responses.txt");
Random rand = new Random();
string response;

case "hello":
    chatBox.Items.Add(Me);
    response = responseLines[rand.Next(responseLines.Length)];
    JARVIS.SpeakAsync(response);
    chatBox.Items.Add("Jarvis: " + response);
    break;
```

The problem is that I want to find ONLY the lines that contains `[hello]` and then randomly pick one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all string in file, split them in two different list:

```
string[] responseLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"responses.txt");
List<string> helloStrings = responseLines.Where<string>(str => str.StartsWith("[hello]")).Select(str => str.Replace("[hello]", "")).ToList<string>();
List<string> goodByeStrings = responseLines.Where<string>(str => str.StartsWith("[goodbye]")).Select(str => str.Replace("[goodbye]", "")).ToList<string>();
```

now pick up a random element from the list you need

Comment: Works too! exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: I tried but i cant? Im new to this site. I think i need atleast 15 reputation?

Comment: Maybe, I'm new to this site too. I upvoted your comment, I think this gave you some reputation point. anyway, not really important.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
string[] responseLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"responses.txt");
```

use

```
string[] responseLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"responses.txt").Where(s => s.Contains("[hello]")).ToArray();
```